# Finding the max and min date values in SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

A lookup table (`tabOne`):

```
    KEY  |  Group  |  Name  |  Desc  | Val_Key
    ----------------------------------------
     1   |     a   | NameA  | DescA  |  10
     2   |     b   | NameB  | DescB  |  20
     3   |     c   | NameC  | DescC  |  30
     4   |     d   | NameD  | DescD  |  40
     5   |     e   | NameE  | DescE  |  50
     6   |     f   | NameF  | DescF  |  60
```

A second table containing readings (`tabTwo`):

```
    KEY  |  Date  |  Reading  | Val_Key
    ----------------------------------------
     1   |  Date   | Read     |  10
     2   |  Date   | Read     |  20
     3   |  Date   | Read     |  40
     4   |  Date   | Read     |  40
     5   |  Date   | Read     |  30
     6   |  Date   | Read     |  20
     7   |  Date   | Read     |  40
     8   |  Date   | Read     |  20
     9   |  Date   | Read     |  10
     10  |  Date   | Read     |  20
     11  |  Date   | Read     |  50
     12  |  Date   | Read     |  60
```

What I need to do is join `tabTwo` with `TabOne` and create a column with the newest Reading and a column with the oldest reading for each item in the group column of `TabOne`.

At the end of the day I want a table that look as follow:

```
    KEY  |  Group  |  Name  |  Desc  | Val_Key | LastReading | FirstReading |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1   |     a   | NameA  | DescA  |  10     |             |              |   
     2   |     b   | NameB  | DescB  |  20     |             |              |
     3   |     c   | NameC  | DescC  |  30     |             |              |
     4   |     d   | NameD  | DescD  |  40     |             |              |
     5   |     e   | NameE  | DescE  |  50     |             |              |
     6   |     f   | NameF  | DescF  |  60     |             |              |
```

Thanks!
Freddie

Comment: What values do you expect in the LastReading and FirstReading columns? We can't guess if you leave those blank...

Comment: The values of the 'Reading' column, sorry I thought that was obvious.

Comment: Well what is "last" and "first"? Does the date column have actual dates in it? What relevance do rows 7-12 have?

Comment: Yes, the date column contains actual dates. Rows 7 - 12 have no significance other to illustrate that the 'tabTwo' is a table that contains a collection of readings. So a item in 'tabONe' (Val_Key = 10) can have multiple readings in 'tabTwo'.

Comment: So the KEY column in tabTwo is irrelevant? The way it is laid out now, I would expect to perform a join on the KEY column, not the Val_Key column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Sql Server 2005 or newer, [outer apply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) will help:

```
select TabOne.*, 
       last.Reading LastReading, 
       first.Reading FirstReading
from TabOne
outer apply
(
  select top 1
         Reading
    from TabTwo
   where TabTwo.Val_Key = TabOne.val_Key
  order by TabTwo.Date desc
) last
outer apply
(
  select top 1
         Reading
    from TabTwo
   where TabTwo.Val_Key = TabOne.val_Key
  order by TabTwo.Date asc
) first
```

[Live test is @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef7af/1).

Answer (score 0):

[@Nikola Markovinović's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10739166/297408) can be made more universally applicable if the subqueries are moved directly to the main query's SELECT clause, which is possible each of them retrieves only one value and is, therefore, valid as a scalar expression:

```
SELECT
  t1.[KEY],
  t1.[Group],
  t1.Name,
  t1.[Desc],
  t1.Val_Key,
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 Reading
    FROM TabTwo
    WHERE Val_Key = t1.Val_Key
    ORDER BY Date DESC
  ) AS LastReading,
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 Reading
    FROM TabTwo
    WHERE Val_Key = t1.Val_Key
    ORDER BY Date ASC
  ) AS FirstReading
FROM TabOne t1
```

If you needed e.g. dates along the way, you would probably have to stick to Nikola's solution. There is an alternative to it, but it's more cumbersome (albeit more standard too): it would involve grouping `TabTwo`'s data by `Val_Key` to get earliest/latest dates per `Val_Key`, then joining back to `TabTwo` to access entire rows corresponding to the found dates to finally pull the necessary columns, and ultimately joining both result sets to `TabOne` to get the final column set.